# Google now Flight reservation card: time of departure wrong display

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I am using microdata to display boarding pass cards for flights.
It works fine on most phones, except on the 2 phone below where departure time displays wrongly:
         Galaxy Code Plus, using Android 5.2.33.16 
         Galaxy Trend Lite ( GT-S7390 )

The time displayed on those 2 phones is UTC instead of local :user is in Portugual.
As a result, display is OK with winter time, but one hour too early with summer time . 
The phone is set up with "Automatic Time Zone".

Time is wrong only on the boarding pass card, please see screenshots below where you can see it displays as 18:05 in the flight info but as 1705 in the boarding pass

[image: Itinerary: departure 18:05]
[image: BP: departure 17:05]

The same email received on other phones displays the time correctly regardless of the location .

The markup for departure time ( already validated by google ) is in format ( sorry I do not have the markup corresponding to  the screenshots):
    `<meta itemprop="departureTime" content="2015-09-16T07:30&#43;01:00">`

Anyone has similar issue ?
Renaud

Comment: What was the date of the flight? I do see Portugal's time was set back to an hour (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/portugal/lisbon) on 10/25/2015, was this around that time?

Comment: We did many tests, starting from july and all before 25th oct .